# Can the wavelet bispectrum be normalised so that its integral "gives the right answer"?

Tags: signal-analysis, wavelets

Fix a rapidly decreasing function $\psi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ with the properties that $\int_\mathbb{R} \psi = 0$, $\mathrm{Re}(\psi(\cdot))$ is an even function, and $\mathrm{Im}(\psi(\cdot))$ is an odd function.

Given any bounded integrable function $x \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, define
\begin{align*}
\hat{x}(\xi) \ :=& \ \int_\mathbb{R} x(\tau)e^{-2\pi i\xi\tau} \, d\tau \\
\mathring{x}(\xi,t) \ :=& \ \int_\mathbb{R} x(\tau)\psi(\xi(\tau-t)) \, d\tau
\end{align*}
for all $\xi,t \in \mathbb{R}$. (Obviously $\hat{x}$ is the Fourier transform; $\mathring{x}$ is a version of the wavelet transform.)

It is known that

> > $$ \hspace{20mm} \int_\mathbb{R} x(t)^2 \, dt \ = \ \int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{x}(\xi)|^2 \, d\xi \ = \ C_\psi\!\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} |\mathring{x}(\xi,t)^2\xi| \, d\xi dt \hspace{18mm} (1) $$

where $C_\psi$ is a constant that depends only on $\psi$ and not on $x$, namely
$$ C_\psi \ = \ \left( \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\hat{\psi}(r)^2}{|r|} \, dr \right)^{\!-1}\,. $$
It is also known that the first equality in $(1)$ can be extended to the 3rd moment by

> > $$\hspace{26mm} \int_\mathbb{R} x(t)^3 \, dt \ = \ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \hat{x}(\xi_1)\hat{x}(\xi_2)\overline{\hat{x}(\xi_1+\xi_2)} \, d\xi_1d\xi_2 \hspace{24mm} (2) $$

where the bar denotes complex conjugate. This naturally leads to the question of whether the second equality in $(1)$ can be extended to the 3rd moment; in case it helps, we can assume that $x$ is a test function:

> > Does there exist a function $f_\psi \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ such that for every real-valued test function $x \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$,
> >     $$ \int_\mathbb{R} x(t)^3 \, dt \ = \ \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \mathring{x}(\xi_1,t)\mathring{x}(\xi_2,t)\overline{\mathring{x}(\xi_1+\xi_2,t)} \, f_\psi(\xi_1,\xi_2) d\xi_1d\xi_2dt \, ? $$
> >     (If not, then [a more open-ended question] are there reasonable conditions on $\psi$ under which one can find a function $f_\psi$ such that the above equality "approximately" holds?)

A little bit of numerical experimentation by a friend and myself seems to suggest that the function
$$ f_\psi(\xi_1,\xi_2) \ = \ D_\psi\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)\!}(\xi_1,\xi_2)(\xi_1+\xi_2) $$
might work for some constant $D_\psi \in \mathbb{C}$.

[**Remark.** In all the above formulae (except possibly the unknown formula in the question itself), one only needs to consider positive $\xi$-values:

- $\int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{x}|^2 = 2\int_{[0,\infty)} |\hat{x}|^2$;
- $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathcal{B}x = 6\int_{[0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)} \mathcal{B}x\ $ where $\mathcal{B}x$ is the integrand in the RHS of $(2)$;
- due to our assumptions on the symmetry of $\psi$, $\int_\mathbb{R} |\mathring{x}(\xi,t)^2\xi| \, d\xi = 2\int_{[0,\infty)} |\mathring{x}(\xi,t)|^2\xi \, d\xi$;

this is why my conjectured form of $f_\psi$ is restricted to nonnegative $\xi$-values.]

---

**UPDATE:** I must admit, it is starting to look unlikely to me that a function $f_\psi$ with the desired property exists. I think I can show that
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{RHS} &= \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{-f_\psi(\xi_1,\xi_2)}{\xi_1\xi_2(\xi_1\!+\xi_2)} \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \hat{\psi}(\tfrac{\omega_1}{\xi_1})\hat{\psi}(\tfrac{\omega_2}{\xi_2})\hat{\psi}(\tfrac{{\color{blue}\omega_{{\color{blue}1}}}{\color{blue}+}{\color{blue}\omega_{{\color{blue}2}}}}{{\color{blue}\xi_{{\color{blue}1}}}{\color{blue}+}{\color{blue}\xi_{{\color{blue}2}}}}) \hat{x}(\omega_1)\hat{x}(\omega_2)\hat{x}(\omega_1\!+\omega_2) \, d\omega_1d\omega_2 \, d\xi_1d\xi_2 \\ 
\mathrm{LHS} &= \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \ \ \frac{D_\psi}{\xi_1\xi_2} \ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \hat{\psi}(\tfrac{\omega_1}{\xi_1})\hat{\psi}(\tfrac{\omega_2}{\xi_2})\hat{\psi}(\tfrac{{\color{blue}\omega_{{\color{blue}1}}}}{{\color{blue}\xi_{{\color{blue}1}}}} {\color{blue}+} \tfrac{{\color{blue}\omega_{{\color{blue}2}}}}{{\color{blue}\xi_{{\color{blue}2}}}}) \hat{x}(\omega_1)\hat{x}(\omega_2)\hat{x}(\omega_1\!+\omega_2) \, d\omega_1d\omega_2 \, d\xi_1d\xi_2
\end{align*}
where $D_\psi$ is some constant.

After the inner double integral, the only difference between the two formulae is what is highlighted in blue. If it were not for this difference, the conjectured solution $f_\psi=\mathrm{cst}\!\cdot\!(\xi_1+\xi_2)$ would work.

However, I think I can also show that the conjectured solution is guaranteed to give $0$ rather than $\int_\mathbb{R} x(t)^3 \, dt$.

Comment: There was an important typo that I've now corrected: $\xi$ is *not* squared in the integrand of the rightmost-hand side of $(1)$.

Comment: This the best I can come up with (using Morlet's reconstruction formula), four integrals instead of three: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)^3\,dt=\frac{1}{D^3_\psi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\int_0^\infty d\xi_1\int_0^\infty d\xi_2\int_0^\infty d\xi_3$$
$$\xi_1^{-3/2}\xi_2^{-3/2}\xi_3^{-3/2}\mathring{x}(\xi_1,t)\mathring{x}(\xi_2,t)\mathring{x}(\xi_3,t)$$

Comment: Thanks, this is a very insightful first step. By the way, where you write $\xi_1^{-3/2}\xi_2^{-3/2}\xi_3^{-3/2}$, I think it should just be $\xi_1\xi_2\xi_3$; for the sake of analogy with the Fourier transform, I have not defined the wavelet transform in quite the standard way.

Comment: Since the Morlet reconstruction formula can be used to obtain the first moment and the more standard reconstruction formula is used to derive the second moment (Kaiser, p69), perhaps the *general reconstruction formula* in Note 2 of the top answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579199/morlets-wavelet-reconstruction-formula can be used to obtain the answer to my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I can prove that my conjectured answer just integrates to give $0$.